# Find a panel in a asp page with panel id

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

in my app i fetch the panel id from database and in webpage i need to find the panel with that id i need to make it visible false.
code behind is

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try
            Dim kioskxml As String = "pnlfindid"
            Dim myControl1 As Control = Page.FindControl(kioskxml)
            If (Not myControl1 Is Nothing) Then
                myControl1.Visible = False

            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

but by the above code snippet, I cannot fetch the panel but it works fine with controls like textbox and other.
I need a way to find the panel with id on page load

My Html Page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div onload="disableBackButton();">
    <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlfindId" runat="server">
          <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
                <td> 
                <asp:Panel ID="pane3" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
                     </td>

                    </tr>


                 </table>

                   </asp:Panel>
             </td>

       </tr>


  </table>
```

```
     </asp:Content>
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that `pannelID` exists in page.

Comment: ya panelId exists in page still mycontrol is nothing in the context

Comment: @AravindGoud Is this panel dynamically generated?

Comment: Probably the control is inside other control and you should retrieve it with recursion. I could show you some code with C# if you want.

Comment: No panel is already there in the page i need to find the pannel and make it visible false @Tushar Gupta

Comment: @AravindGoud so why do you need to find control why not pannelID.visible = false

Comment: @AravindGoud If its already there thene why dont you do `pannelID.visible=false`

Comment: ya panel is inside <asp:content> Like this
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Panel ID="pnlId" runat="server"> 


 </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>

@mybirthname

Comment: @meda I will be retrieving the panel id from database

Comment: @AravindGoud are you sure the content has been loaded when you try to find the panel?

Comment: @TusharGupta I will be retrieving the panelids from database

Comment: it would help if you could post your html side as well

Comment: Then why can't you use `pnlId.Visible = false;` directly instead of `FindControl` ?

Comment: @ShubhadaFuge i am using the above code in page Load event

Comment: @AravindGoud Please post the HTML... also, is this code written on Master page's load event?

Comment: @AravindGoud I have provided the solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to find the control in the content pages's load event as opposed to master page's load event.

You will need to first find the contentplaceholder and then find the panel within contentplaceholder
As I am not familiar with VB.NET syntax, I am providing C# syntax:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cont = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
Panel myPanel = cont.FindControl(kioskxml);
```

Ofcourse, else, if you are doing it on Master page's page load event,

```
 ContentPlaceHolder cont = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
 Panel myPanel = cont.FindControl(kioskxml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need

```
Dim myControl1 As Control = Master.FindControl(kioskxml)
```

or

```
Dim myControl1 As Control = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl(kioskxml)
```

everything else looks fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try

            Dim myControl1 As Control =directcast(Page.FindControl("pnlfindid"),Control)
            If (Not myControl1 Is Nothing) Then
                myControl1.Visible = False

            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```